# JavaScript declaring variable as " g = g || {}; " what does it means?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

Good day, was reading a JavaScript script library and come across this

> var g = g || {};

What does this means?

Comment: It's like if the g variable doesn't exist then create an object. Assigning both to g variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to ensure g is actually initialized as an object. It is the same as:

```
if(!g) g = {};
```

The || is an OR. The second operand will be returned only if the first one evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks. nice explanation. Didn't know you can do that. will mark as correct once 10 min pass..

Answer (score 2):

It means, that if g is 0/null/undefined, the g will be defined as an empty object.

The common way:

```
function foo(g) {
    // If the initial g does not defined, null or 0
    if(!g) {
      // Define g as an empty object
      g = {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript returns the first argument if true, otherwise the second one. This is equivalent to an OR.

So in your example, if g is not set, it is set to an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Following description is taken from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

> expr1 || expr2
>   Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand can be converted to true; if both can be converted to false, returns false.

In your case, if `g` has a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (false/null/undefined/0/NaN/''/(document.all)[[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)]), then `g` will be set with `{}`